# Converting a 3D object create with vertexes to Faces

Tags: javascript, three.js

So I have an object that I created by drawing vertexes on a 3D canvas using Three.JS. Now I am trying to add faces to to it but I can not seem to get the correct method for this.

You can find the project here: https://github.com/thebillkidy/WebGL-SuperFormula (Basically it is applying the Superformula in WebGL)

I already tried point clouds, lines and ConvexGeometries but none seem to work. Anyone knows how to do this?

P.S. You can find my current render method here: https://github.com/thebillkidy/WebGL-SuperFormula/blob/master/app/scripts/main.js I also added the other methods that I tried.

Comment: So your general question is: "how do I convert a point cloud to faces?" or if it is just drawing points on the superformula, just iterate loops on theta and phi and follow the face topology of a typical sphere. Look in the definition within THREE.js for the SphereGeometry() object, and modify the usual spherical-point formula to use the superformula instead.

Comment: Yes, a collection of vertexes but I need faces mapped to them.

Comment: (previous comment edited)

Comment: Thank you so much, did what you told me and it is working! :D